# Таймер обратного времени

Tags: javascript, jquery, таймер

Добрый день! Есть скрипт редиректа с таймером обратного времени. В скрипте задаешь время, и он при открытии страницы отсчитывает время. Когда доходит до нуля, то продолжает считать уже в минусе. Как сделать, чтобы он доходил до нуля, и после этого span id timer_page2 становился display:none? Помогите, пожалуйста. Спасибо!

```
var time = 12;
var page = "#page2";

function countDown(){
    time--;
    gett("timer_page2").innerHTML = time;
    if(time == 0){
        window.location = page;
    }
 }

 function gett(id){
    if(document.getElementById) 
        return document.getElementById(id);
    if(document.all) 
        return document.all.id;
    if(document.layers) 
        return document.layers.id;
    if(window.opera) 
        return window.opera.id;
 }

 function init(){
    if(gett('timer_page2')){
        setInterval(countDown, 1000);
        gett("timer_page2").innerHTML = time;
    } else {
        setTimeout(init, 50);
    }
}

document.onload = init();

<span id='timer_page2'></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией `clearInterval`:

```
var timer;
var time = 12;
var page = "#page2";
function countDown() {
    time--;
    gett("timer_page2").innerHTML = time;
    if (time == 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        gett("timer_page2").style.display = "none";
        //gett("timer_page2").innerHTML = ""; // второй вариант!
        window.location = page;
    }
}
function gett(id) {
    if (document.getElementById) return document.getElementById(id);
    if (document.all) return document.all.id;
    if (document.layers) return document.layers.id;
    if (window.opera) return window.opera.id;
}
function init() {
    if (gett('timer_page2')) {
        timer = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
        gett("timer_page2").innerHTML = time;
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(init, 50);
    }
}
document.onload = init();
```

Comment: В таком случае останавливается на нуле, и ноль остается. А как же сделать, чтобы именно span id timer_page2 становился display:none? В любом случае очень благодарен вам за помощь!

Comment: Внес исправления. Там есть два варианта избавиться от 0.

Comment: Да, всё чудесно работает! Огромное вам спасибо за помощь!